# Transform between relational database and graph-based database

Tags: algorithm, graph, relational-database, rdbms, graph-databases

I am aware that there are algorithms (and even tools) to transform relational databases (RDBMS) to Graph databases, and the other way around.

I do have several questions that are a bit larger than that:

1. Is there a common-practice working algorithm out there for such transformation, for example RDBMS => graph (or several)?
2. Is this algorithm bijective? To be more precise:

   2.1. Given said algorithm, is the transformation RDBMS => graph injective (one-to-one)? More plainly, can there be any two relational DBs that can be transformed into the same Graph DB?

   2.2. Similarly, is any Graph DB can be represented by a relational DB? Basically, I'm asking if the algorithm function is surjective (onto)?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

There's typically an obvious bijection from a particular math notion of graph (node set, edge relation) to a relational representation. Essentially because the math uses sets and relations.

There's no standard graph DBMS. And no standard way to use one to represent application/business situations. So there's no standard mapping between a graph database state & a relational state, let alone one that gives a representation in the other that is natural for the situations represented.

Without relation-valued attributes, mappings are not always bijective between non-relational structures and relational structures because we must sometimes pick relational surrogate values 1:1 with the relation values we would have used.

---

Sometimes we're not interested in a particular situation, we are just interested in a data structure. Then we can come up with (various) relational versions of it.

But a database or data structure variable typically represents an application/business situation. There is typically a one-to-many or one-to-one mapping from situations to representations. Under the relational model, every table has an associated *(characteristic) predicate* (statement template) and holds the rows that make a true *proposition* (statement) from its predicate. Other data structures are used in an ad hoc way to represent a situation.

What's special about the relational model is that you can generically query via predicate logic and/or relation operators--a query expression determines a predicate and its result holds the rows that make a true proposition from its predicate. (Calculated with certain complexity guarantees and certain opportunities for automated optimization.)

Mappings between structures *that represent the same situation* depend on how the databases represent situations. So there is no general mapping between representations, even for two representations using the same data structure.

On the other hand you can define some generic mapping between two structures, and it might be bijective, but when a situation is represented by one, the other tells you about *the other representation* of the situation, hence the situation only indirectly, not the situation itself directly. So don't expect the relational version that describes the other structure's representaion to be anything like a good relational design for that application/business.

This is the problem with ORMs & object databases. You can define a mapping from a particular object-oriented state to relations but the relations are only describing the object-oriented state, not its represented situation. Every time an object value holds an oid to an object referenced rather than contained, that referencing object is representing a relationship/association entity instance. But usually *there is no explicit predicate given for the relation corresponding to the set of such objects*. Instead we are given a representation function from some entire representing state to a represented situation. Whereas in a relational design *every superkey value of every table (base or query result)* is 1:1 with some (possibly associative) entity.