# Elaboration on Foreign Keys in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'd love someone to help talk me through a problem I'm working on. I don't have much database experience, but I'm trying to teach myself MySQL for a personal project relating to cryptocurrencies. Basically, I'm trying to store key-value pairs from a python program, which is parsing json from an exchange's api, into a database. I've written out a possible solution based on my limited knowledge of databases:

```
OVERALL TABLE STRUCTURE:
TICKER = FK OF ENTRIES 
ORDERBOOKS = FK to table relating orderbooks and timestamps
MARKET_HISTORIES = FK to table relating market histories and timestamps
MARKET_SUMMARIES = FK to table relating market summaries and timestamps

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       KEY       | TICKER |         ORDERBOOKS            |         MARKET_HISTORIES        |        MARKET_SUMMARIES         | TIMESTAMP |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| autoincremented |BTC-LTC |hash("BTC-LTC, "ob",timestamp)| hash("BTC-LTC","mh",timestamp) | hash("BTC-LTC","ms",timestamp) |  datetime |
   (unused)                                                                                                 
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MySQL schtuff:
CREATE TABLE test_table( 
p_key INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
ticker VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
orderbooks INT NOT NULL, 
market_histories INT NOT NULL, 
market_summaries INT NOT NULL, 
timestamp INT, 
PRIMARY KEY (p_key));


___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

FOREIGN KEY = hash of ticker and "ob", used to access all orderbooks relating to the ticker
timestamp = unix timestamp from when the insertion began at the overall structure

ORDERBOOKS
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        KEY      | FOREIGN KEY | TIMESTAMP |             BUYS_KEY             |             SELLS_KEY            |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| autoincremented |  FK passed  | timestamp | hash(FK passed, "bk", timestamp) | hash(FK passed, "sk", timestamp) |
    (unused)

BUYS

 ----------------------------------------------------
|        KEY         | FOREIGN KEY | QUANTITY | RATE |
 ----------------------------------------------------
| autoincremented PK | buys_key    |   float  | float|
       (unused)



SELLS

 ----------------------------------------------------
|        KEY         | FOREIGN KEY | QUANTITY | RATE |
 ----------------------------------------------------
| autoincremented PK | sells_key   |   float  | float|
       (unused)

_______________________________________________________________________________________________



FOREIGN KEY = hash of ticker and "mh", used to reference Market History entries
timestamp = unix timestamp from when the insertion began at the overall structure

MARKET HISTORY
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        KEY      | FOREIGN KEY | TIMESTAMP |           RESULT_KEY             |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| autoincremented |  FK passed  | timestamp | hash(FK passed, "mh", timestamp) |
    (unused)

RESULT_MH

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        KEY         | FOREIGN KEY | ID | UNIQUE_TIMESTAMP | QUANTITY | PRICE | TOTAL | FILLTYPE | ORDERTYPE |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| autoincremented PK | results_key | int| datetime object? |  float   | float | float |  string  |  string   |
       (unused)
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________


FOREIGN KEY = hash of ticker and "ms", used to reference Market Summary entries
timestamp = unix timestamp from when the insertion began at the overall structure

MARKET SUMMARY
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        KEY      | FOREIGN KEY | TIMESTAMP |           RESULT_KEY             |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| autoincremented |  FK passed  | timestamp | hash(FK passed, "ms", timestamp) |
    (unused)


RESULT_MS
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        KEY         | FOREIGN KEY | HIGH | LOW | VOLUME | LAST | BASEVOLUME | UNIQUE_TIMESTAMP | BID | ASK | OPEN_BUY_ORDERS | OPEN_SELL_ORDERS | PREVDAY | CREATED |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| autoincremented PK | results_key | float|float| float  | float|   float    | datetime object? |float|float|       int       |        int       |  float  | datetime|
       (unused)
```

So the issue/confusion I'm running into is how to get all these foreign keys to relate to each other and how programatically I can even get that to work. Based on what I've read, I'm assuming the MySQL code would be something similar to: Foreign Key(orderbook) references orderbooks(foreign_key), does that sound about right? I want to be able to store specific snapshots of a market and access them at will.

For instance, if I took a snapshot of a market right now at UNIX time 1499882777, then took another snapshot at UNIX time 1499882800, I want to be able to access both entries and access all relevant data at those times (orderbook, market history, market summary).

Am I on the right track here? I'm very new to databases and want to make this as efficient/robust as I can.

Thanks in advance for the input! :D

EDIT 1: 
After re-reading this for what must be the 20th time, I'm wondering if I'm overcomplicating the market history and the market summary tables

EDIT 2:
I took a swing at this in the mysql executable with this: 
`create table fk_test( p_key INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
fk INT, buys_key INT, 
sells_key INT, 
PRIMARY KEY (p_key), 
FOREIGN KEY (fk) REFERENCES test_table(orderbooks));`

Getting this error: `ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: Read [intros to information modeling & relational databases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007275/3404097). You appear to be just trying to persist the state of a python program. [The idea is to model your *application* not some other representation of your application.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45028926/3404097)

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to put the result of a json http request from an exchange's API into a database. I'm only using python to retrieve the data and (hopefully) store it in MySQL

Comment: You're unclear. Please briefly describe your application/business situations. (Buys, sells, ticker, orderbooks, histories, summaries.) Then precisely describe what you want to persist. If it's some python or api state, describe it in terms of its data structures & say how to map between a situation & its representing data structure. Whatever you have in mind for relational tables (situations? data structures?) tell us each table *predicate*--what a row says when in it, in terms of its column names, about whatever you are persisting. Your code block is a cypher. And don't mention PKs or FKs.

Comment: Please ask your debugging question in a separate post. Please put some research effort in before, ie google error codes & google how to find out more about errors & like every question google many clear, concise, specific phrasings of your question & tags and read many hits, and if you still have a question use one phrasing as your title. Read and act on [mcve]. Lack of research is a downvote reason & lack of a MVCE when debugging is a close reason.